# adding my custom variants in typography mui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

I am trying to implement my own typography for my typescript nextjs project. I am unable to configure my code for it thus it is not working, can someone please help or guide me how to introduce my own typography.

**typography.ts file:**

```js
export const typography = {
    fontFamily: 'Recoleta, Fira Sans',
    htmlFontSize: 10,
    h7: {
      'fontFamily': 'Recoleta',
      'fontSize': '1.0rem',
      'fontWeight': 'bold',
      'fontStretch': 'normal',
      'fontStyle': 'normal',
      'lineHeight': 1.4,
    }
};
```

**muiThemeOveride.ts:**

```js
import {createTheme} from '@mui/material/styles';
import {responsiveFontSizes} from '@mui/material/styles';

import { typography } from "./typography";

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface TypographyVariants {
    h7: React.CSSProperties;
  }

  // allow configuration using `createTheme`
  interface TypographyVariantsOptions {
    h7?: React.CSSProperties;
  }
}

// Update the Typography's variant prop options
declare module '@mui/material/Typography' {
  interface TypographyPropsVariantOverrides {
    h7: true;
    h3: false;
  }
}
export const theme = responsiveFontSizes(createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        outlined: {
          borderColor: black,
          color: black,
          '&:hover': {
            borderColor: black,
          }
        }
      },
    },
  },
  typography
}));
```

**index.ts**

```js
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta
          content="Generated by create next app"
          name="description" />
        <link
          href="/favicon.ico"
          rel="icon"
        />
      </Head>

      <main>
  
        <Typography variant="h7" >HELLO</Typography>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

I have updated imports in the MUI theme config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the import for typography override that you have written.

You need to import `typography.ts` file in `muiThemeOveride.ts` file and do the following.

```js
import { typography } from "./typography";

export const theme = responsiveFontSizes(createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        outlined: {
          borderColor: black,
          color: black,
          '&:hover': {
            borderColor: black,
          }
        }
      },
    },
  },
  typography
}));
```

Comment: I have imported import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'; I am following https://mui.com/customization/typography/

Comment: @Paladin I am telling about using the code you have written in your `typography.ts` file (where you are overriding `font-family` and other properties) in your `muiThemeOverride.ts` file.
Your `index.ts` file doesn't need any change.
The only file needing change is `muiThemeOverride.ts`

Comment: I have updated my code according to what you were saying but I get the same result.

Comment: I will suggest hosting it on `stackblitz`/`codesandbox` and sharing snippet.
That is the only way I think anyone can help now.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-villani-r8szc?file=/pages/about.tsx  Here's the codesandbox link thankyou

Comment: Your `ThemeProvider` in `pages/_app.tsx` is importing `theme` from `src/theme.ts`, which doesn't have any `Typography` override present.
You either add that `Typography` override in `src/theme.ts` or import the theme from `src/constants/muiThemeOverride.tsx`

Comment: @Paladin, please upvote and accept the answer once it works.

Comment: Thankyou for the help.

Comment: Already done Thanks @jaybhatt